# What is the speed at which the wedges recede?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

A plank is held at some height between two smooth wedges of inclination $45^{\text{o}}$. If the plank moves down at a speed $v$, at what speed will the wedges recede?

[image]

Could someone give me a hint how to set up the proper constraint relation between the speed of the plank and that of the wedge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Method 1:

During a given time the block would move vertically downwards by a length equal to the vertical of the blue triangle this is the same time taken for the wedge to move out of the way that is to move by a length equal to the horizontal of the blue triangle. Formulate equations accordingly.

Method 2:

Internal forces sum up to zero,

$$\sum F.X =0 $$

Differentiating,

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]
{
\sum F.V =0
}
$$

Here $F$ is the internal force, the normal force between the blocks in your question, $V$ will be the velocity of a particular block.$\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. The sum of $F.V.\cos \theta$ for each block will equate to zero.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the second method? I don't quite get how to use it.

Comment: @ijm I edited the answer instead of explaining it in the comments.